# How to pass an array of C-Strings to a function

Tags: c++

Normally I would just pass an array into a function, however, I am doing a homework assignment and my professor says to use an array of C-Strings and I want to use a function.  However, I can not think of how to send this to a function.  Any help would be great.

Comment: tagging this question "homework"

Comment: Let's see if I can clarify I will update my question.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I appreciate the answers but I realized that there may be one detail I left out which I will work on tomorrow and maybe get help from my schools tutor lab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as a double pointer:

```
type myFunc(char **array) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since a c-string is really just an array of chars, wouldn't you just pass an array of arrays of chars?

Comment: Normally, someone talking about an array of C strings would be talking about an array of pointers to several different arrays-of-char.

Answer (score 0):

Well, do you know the syntax for an array? Do you know the syntax for a function? How would you guess an array would be passed as an argument?

If you're not sure, take a look in your C/C++ textbook.

Comment: I have read the text this whole day...I made this function `void sortArray(char uniqueWords[],int numUniqueWords, char newWord[])`, however when I want to run `strcmp(uniqueWords[count],newWord)` Visual Studio says "Error: argument of type char is incompatible with type constant char*"

Answer (score 0):

```
char **arr;

arr = malloc (sizeof (char *) * string_count);
for (i=0; i<string_count; i++)
{
  /* get string size */
  arr[i] = malloc (sizeof (char) * this_string_size);
  /* copy string into allocated */
}

function (char **arr, int string_count)
{
}
```

Remember to free memory after use.

OR

```
char *arr[NOS_OF_SRINGS];

for (i=0; i<NOS_OF_STRINGS; i++)
  arr[i] = malloc (sizeof (char) * string_length);


function (char *arr[NOS_OF_STRINGS])
{
}
```

Remember to free the allocated memory blocks.

OR

```
char arr[NOS_OF_STRINGS][STR_LENGTH];

/* copy stuffs */

function (char arr[NOS_OF_STRINGS][STR_LENGTH])
{
}
```